Will i feel a shock if i put my finger in a spontaneously working Daniel cell?
Consider two beakers, A and B. Now Beaker A has zinc sulphate solution with a zinc rod dipped, and Beaker B has copper sulphate solution with a copper rod dipped in it. We know that oxidation potential of zinc is high and reduction potential of copper is high. So due to a potential difference, zinc will get oxidized and copper will get reduced, therfore  electrons will flow through the zinc rod to the copper rod. So zinc(+2) ions would be released in the solution of zinc sulphate and copper(+2) ions would be reduced to copper in the other Beaker. Now if I put my finger in the electrolytic solution of any of the beakers, will I feel a shock? If yes, then why, because electrons are introduced in the solution. If no, then why? Also compare this scenario with a electric wire cut and kept in water. Please answer this question, I am dying to know what will happen.

The shock would be about the same as from a battery.

Electrons would flow, but you most likely would not feel a shock.  Such a cell makes 1.1V, which is less than a fully charged AA battery.
The situation with a wire in it is more complicated, because a wire is a "short."  Skin immersed in water has a resistance of 150 ohms.  Since that is a simple resistor, we can use $V=IR$ to compute that the current would be about 7.3mA.  This is a low enough current that there's a good chance the cells have the time to replenish the balance of electrolytes over the salt bridge.  If you put a wire between them, the resistance is on the order of 1 milliohm.  By $V=IR$ that would suggest a current of 1100A, which is quite obviously not possible to sustain.  What will actually happen in that case is that the circuit will not be able to move the electrolytes fast enough.  The voltage will dip (likely to nearly 0) because the current can travel across the wire so much easier than the redox equations can complete.

Why will electrons flow into the electrolytic solution? Aren't they supposed to fow from anode to cathode?

You won't feel a shock. The charge carriers in solution are not electrons. They are dissolved copper and zinc ions in solution. For you to feel a shock, either copper or zinc would have to be reduced at your finger allowing the transfer of electrons through your finger. You would only feel a shock if you touched both bare electrodes at the same time.
